# barman does not accept parameter 'target-time'

Tags: postgresql, parameters, backup, barman

I try to recover a barman backup, and I want to use the parameter `target-time`. But barman does not accept this parameter, even if I use it in the same manner like many sources I found.
The whole output:

```bash
barman@BKUP-XXX:~$ barman recover --target-time '2023–04–22 00:00:00.000000+02:00' --remote-ssh-command "ssh postgres@pgdb-XXX" PGDB-XXX 20230416T214125 /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/
Starting remote restore for server PGDB-XXX using backup 20230416T214125
Destination directory: /var/lib/postgresql/13/main/
Remote command: ssh postgres@pgdb-XXX
ERROR: Unable to parse the target time parameter '2023–04–22 00:00:00.000000+02:00': Unknown string format: 2023–04–22 00:00:00.000000+02:00
barman@BKUP-XXX:~$
```

The string format of the time is unknown. But it's exactly the format used in many examples, no matter if with or without milliseconds or timezone, every time I try is unknown.
Maybe it's a python issue? The server is used only for barman, I don't think, there is another software with interdependencies to barman or python.
How can I use the `target-time`?

Comment: All examples I can find, use "" instead of '' around the timestamp.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I tried both, it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--target-time` option should accept any timestamp allowed by the [PostgreSQL recovery_target_time parameter](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-WAL-RECOVERY-TARGET).

Your particular `--target-time` value is using [en dashes](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=2023%E2%80%9304%E2%80%9322+00%3A00%3A00.000000%2B02%3A00) (`–`, UTF-8 code: `E2 80 93`) instead of hyphens (`-`, UTF-8 code: `2D`). If you replace the dashes with hyphens then the timestamp will be accepted, e.g.: `2023-04-22 00:00:00.000000+02:00`.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not absolutly sure, if this is the correct answer, but ist sounds very plausible. It was strange, next time after a few days I tried the command it worked like expected, and I don't had any clue what was the difference. But maybe I used the wrong hyphens, anf if so, I have no idea, how I got these. I tried it many times, and I used the keyboard, no copy&paste. But I assume, this answer is correct. Thank you!

Comment: There are definitely some applications out there (google docs I think is one, possibly some wikis) which will auto-format a hyphen as a dash - I've certainly be bitten by that before.